# iOS App with Free trial and subscribe after that

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

So we have an app under `Health & Fitness` category. The app is based on only one main functionality and no other sub functionalities. Now, the client would want to give users some free trial period like 7 days and if the user likes the app they can subscribe to continue using the app, if they choose not to subscribe they will not be able to use the app any further. So, I have done some research and came up with this result:

**Option 1: Lite version/Paid version**

Obviously I don't see any hope that this would work for us. Since we cannot split the main functionality.

**Option 2: In-App Purchase**

*Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396357/ios-trial-app-without-in-app-purchase-mechanism*

From [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#terms-conditions)

- 11.8 Apps that use IAP to purchase access to built-in capabilities provided by iOS, watchOS, and tvOS, such as the camera or the
  gyroscope, or Apple-branded peripherals, such as Apple Pencil or
  Apple Keyboard, or Apple services, such as Apple Music access or
  iCloud storage, will be rejected
- 11.9 Apps containing content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected, except for specific approved content (e.g.
  films, television programs, music, books)

As far as I understood, it states that Apps under `Magazine & Newspapers` category alone utilize this exception. Is that correct?
And it states we should not block the entire activity of the app instead we should limit the usage, is that correct?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The App Store Review Guidelines are clear, an app that expires will be rejected:

> 11.9 **Apps containing content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected**, except for specific approved content (e.g. films, television programs, music, books)

## Contact Apple

Talk to Apple's App Store staff about how best to approach your app and how to avoid being rejected:

> #### App Review
>
> Find out the status of your app and [submit general questions](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) for the App Review Team.

Answer (score 1):

Current practice does seem to allow this nowadays, for instance the Moleskine Flow app, recently promoted on the App Store, offers an initial 14-day free unlock, and trial afterwards.

I dont know if there is any functionality after the trial period, yet, but there is no way to use the app without accepting the trial.